# System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column

Tags: c#, sorting, user-controls

I am implementing girdview sorting, which is part of a user control. The code below gives me Indexoutofrange error.

The error message is:

```
dtView.Sort = strSort;
Errormessage: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find column TEXT_COUNTY_ID.
```

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Really appreciate your help.

```
protected void SortGridData_Hkl(Object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView _dgd_work_onoff = (GridView)Page.FindControl("bodyuc$dgd_work_onoff");
            DataSet dstemp;
            DataView dtView;
            if (ViewState["dsfetchResults"] != null)
            {
                dstemp = (DataSet)ViewState["dsfetchResults"];
                string strSortOrder = ViewState["SortOrder"].ToString();

                if (strSortOrder == "DESC")
                {
                    strSortOrder = "ASC";
                    ViewState["SortOrder"] = strSortOrder;
                }
                else
                {
                    strSortOrder = "DESC";
                    ViewState["SortOrder"] = strSortOrder;
                }

                string strSort = e.SortExpression.ToString() + " " + strSortOrder;
                ViewState["SortString"] = strSort;

                dtView = dstemp.Tables[0].DefaultView;

                dtView.Sort = strSort;
                if (dtView.Count != 0)
                {
                    if (_dgd_work_onoff != null)
                    {
                        _dgd_work_onoff.DataSource = dtView;
                        _dgd_work_onoff.DataBind();
                    }
                }


            }
```

`dsfetchResults` is supposed to contain the data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. the issue was that I used a different column name in the design (.aspx) than the one in the database.